# C# - Error Using Code Previously Posted Here

Tags: c#

I am attempting to use the code found in the answer here: [Directory.Move doesn't work (file already exist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553008/directory-move-doesnt-work-file-already-exist)

This is exactly the method I need, but when I try to add it to my code, the line

`Directory.CreateDirectory(folders.Target);`

has the word "Target" underlined in red, and the error is "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Target' and no extension method 'Target' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Can anyone help me get rid of that error?

Comment: Matteo - but it should, since folders is defined as the output of a stack, whose input was an object of type Folders, which does have that property defined

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - you presumably haven't declared `folders` as being of type `Folders`, given that it's complaining about `object` not containing `Target`...

Comment: As per Claudio's comment below, you're correct, but what I was trying to do was modify the declaration of `folders`, when instead the solution was to modify the declaration of the stack from which `folders` gets its definition. Thank you!

Comment: Next time you ask a question, you should give much more context - see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: You should better change your title to describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism. What more context would have been helpful in my case specifically? I didn't add much since essentially my question was "I put in this code, but it didn't work and I don't know why". I'd like to know what I can do to be a better Stack user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `Stack` by `Stack<Folders>`

```
var stack = new StackStack<Folders>();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Did you just edit the answer in the original question? I tried but it was already there in the edit window =) I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer goes down

Comment: I've edited it now. It already actually had the generics in the source, but the answer was using HTML tags for the code instead of the markdown approach :(

Answer (score 0):

`Folders.Target` is defined in this class

```
public class Folders
{
    public string Source { get; private set; }
    public string Target { get; private set; }

    public Folders(string source, string target)
    {
        Source = source;
        Target = target;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have that code in there as well, it still doesn't like it though, perhaps because 'folders' is a var and not a member of Folders?

Comment: @user774359 is 'folders' being assigned in the same manner? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: My code was exactly what is available on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553008/directory-move-doesnt-work-file-already-exist, as the first answer. I was just trying to implement it in my particular project, but was receiving an error.