# Moving a folder, from one directory to another. in c#

Tags: c#

Okay, so me and several others are trying to move a bunch of files from a game launcher. To said directory of your choice.

The problem is, the files wont move.

The way the launcher works, is you click install on the game, it installs a bunch of files to the location of your choice. But the files wont move.

Here' the code.

```
    private void MoveFolders()
    {
        string sourceDir = Config.GetGamePath();
        string destinationDir = textBoxFolder.Text;
        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(sourceDir) == true)
            {
                if (bGameIsInstalled == true && textBoxFolder.TextLength > 0)
                {
                    Directory.Move(sourceDir, destinationDir);
                    bMoveFolders = true;
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Select Arma 3 directory before starting game");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Do somthing about source directory not existing - 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Handle the execption that has been thrown will do this on launcher update
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe some exception is thrown?

Comment: We wont debug your code, when you have gone and done that, you will find that either the source/destination string is not what you want. Or it will throw an error (permissions?) and we can go from there.

Comment: Can you provide samples for `sourceDir` and `destinationDir` (do they have same volume/drive letter)?

Comment: see this : [Moving a folder (Directory) from one location to another] http://stackoverflow.com/a/2553245/4736873

this may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***CopyFile***.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) As you said this should be a installer, i wouldn't move them folders to another direction. Just copy it, because you can't use the installer one more time after all these files needed are moved away.
And if you debug it, please just don't use try and catch. Test your code simply.

Comment: But, it's also saying that a file already exists in the directory

Comment: Do you have teamspeak? Lol, i'd love to talk to you about this. Me and my buddy are crazy stuck right now.  If you do join ts3.life-studios.net:3537

Comment: And poke me, Im Blake Hendricks

Comment: Actually i haven't. Anyways I'm going to go lifting in a few minutes. So good luck for now. Just try a more simple verision of the programme like you only try to copy one folder which is empty and if you succeed with it you can expand that.