# Can't find ExtractToDirectory (source,path,boolean) C# VS 2019

Tags: c#, zip, extract, unzip

I'm trying to use ExtractToDirectory function and it's working fine when there is no file exist.
(Unzipping is ok when there is not same file name)
After checking microsoft site and looking at ExtractToDirectory I found there are more 2 overload functions that supposed to shown.

All I can use is:
(source,path) and (source,path,encoding)
no boolean is found (that supposed to show if overwrite is allowed)

Comment: Is that you need ? [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String, String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Are you trying to extract to a folder or an existing zip file?  I think you are trying to extract to a ZIP file and not a folder.  Enable the extension in you file explorer so you know the differences between a folder and a zip file.

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes, somehow I can't use this function (only string, string, encoding)
I need to use (string,string,bool) but the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the method [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String, String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) is only available since *.NET Core 2.0*, not *.NET Framework* nor *.NET Standard*.

It will be available on *.NET 5*.

So on *.NET Framework* you need to delete files of an existing folder before extracting... or use another assembly from another developer:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

if ( Directory.Exists(extractToPath) )
  // Ask user confirmation if needed
  Directory.Delete(extractToPath, true);

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipSourcePath, extractToPath);
```

[System.IO.Directory.Delete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete)

Don't forget to add the reference in the project to the assembly `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` (see images below).

**To only update the destination folder**

With new files in the zip, you can extract the zip in a subfolder in the user temp folder, and next, move this folder to the folder where you have your tree to update.

It should do what you need.

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipSourcePath, tempPath);
```

And next use:

[Directory.Move doesn't work (file already exist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553008/directory-move-doesnt-work-file-already-exist)

```
MoveDirectory(tempPath, extractToPath);
```

Because [Directory.Move(string, string) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move) can't be used since it does not allow overwriting..

Don't hesitate to open a new question if you have difficulty doing that.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought about this idea (to OpenRead and then delete file if exist and unzip)
I'm not that strong in C# so I would like to get your help by helping me coding these lines with this function.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks. one more question:
if ( Directory.Exists(extractToPath) ) -> Checks file(s) name inside ZIP?
After all I need the function to only *update* new files that are from ZIP
For example: inside UPDATE.ZIP there is a text file named: Update.txt
and in @"." (root) there is a file called the same (Update.txt)
I need the file to be deleted and then unzip the new Update.txt

if it works- will this code will work if I need to update specific file in directory?
For example: Update\Update.txt
will it keep the older files but replace only the new? or will delete the whole folder "Update"?

Comment: If you only need to extract some files to update an existing file system tree, I don't know. Perhaps using another component like https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd. Else you can extract the zip in a folder in the user temp folder and next merge it in the destination system tree by moving files

Comment: Both ideas sound very smart but I really don't know how to add a component or how to merge files.. I thought this function will be so easy because of the overwrite and then it became very complicated..
Maybe you can upload something quick here or contact me at "Discord"/"Skype" so we can chat?
Thanks a lot again, you're really helpful.

Comment: I wondered if there's a way to use ZipFile.OpenRead to run all over the zip
and then use your code and check if specific file is exist if yes delete if no extract.

Comment: I succeed to make it work to extract files (if exist delete and extract)
Now I'm having another problem caused by folders inside the zip file.
Example: Update.zip includes Data folder and inside there are files to update
How can I Open the zip check if folder exist and if it exist- save the path and do the same thing until you get to files. (only update the files to direct path inside the zip)
Example: update.zip Data/Text.txt should be extracted to Data/Text.txt
Example 2: update.zip Data/Folder/Text.txt should be extracted to Data/Folder/Text.txt
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, I never used ZipFile and I see that available methods are only Create, Extract, Open and OpenRead... But there is [ZipArchive.Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries). You should be able to parse the content to find what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to use ZipArchive.Entries but I still can't understand how I check if entry is folder

Comment: Didn't the example on the Microsoft page help you navigate the entries (`entry.FullName`) ? Also you can apply Linq extension methods like `Where`, `Any` and so on.