How do I move an entire directory with folders inside?
I am working on a simple mod manager for a game but I can't move the mods from one folder to another. But every time I move something I get this error:
System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
Note that when i get this error it is trying to move a directory from E:\brmodloader\Unloaded Mods to E:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Brick Rigs\BrickRigs\Mods
Code:
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem selecteditem in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                if (selecteditem.SubItems[1].Text == "loaded")
                {
                    string currentItemPath = selecteditem.SubItems[0].Text;
                    Directory.Move(currentItemPath, MODSOFF);
                    ModChecker();
                }
                if (selecteditem.SubItems[1].Text == "unloaded")
                {
                    string currentItemPath = selecteditem.SubItems[0].Text;
                    Directory.Move(currentItemPath, BRDIR + "/BrickRigs/Mods/");
                    ModChecker();
                }
            }
        }


You need to catch and handle that exception.

^^ how, depends on what you need to happen when it is thrown. Do you know what file it is in particular, that is already at the target? Can you safely replace it? Maybe rename and retry?

And you're certain that the destination file doesn't already exist? What happens if you delete the destination directory immediately before calling Directory.Move?

Already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553008/directory-move-doesnt-work-file-already-exist

From Microsoft (emphasis mine),

This method creates a new directory with the name specified by destDirName and moves the contents of sourceDirName, including files and directories, to the newly created destination directory. It then deletes the sourceDirName directory.
If you try to move a directory to a directory that already exists, an IOException will occur.

What is most likely happening is that the directory already exists, and thus when you try to copy to it, it throws a System.IO.IOException, exactally as documented. The error message stating that the "file already exists" rather than the "directory already exists" is probably just a fluke that nobody really cared about because the type of error is the same.
So you have two options:

If the directory already exists, assume that everything you wanted to copy is already there, and quit. This can be done by checking whether or not the directory already exists with Directory.Exists, or by just waiting for the System.IO.IOException and handling it with a try-catch statement.
If the directory already exists, delete it and then do the copy. This can be done by checking whether or not the directory already exists with Directory.Exists, calling the Directory.Delete (with the second recursive parameter set to true, in case the directory contains files or subdirectories, in which case the one-parameter version or the version with recursive being false would throw an error), and then calling Directory.Move, or I'm fairly sure just calling Directory.Delete from the get go would work since I don't see anything in the documentation that would indicate it would throw an error were the directory not to exist in the first place.

It might also be a good idea to just quickly check out the directory in File Explorer to make sure there isn't anything you wouldn't want overridden there.
